# Существует ли лимит у strings.xml?

Tags: android, android-resources

Существует ли лимит по количеству строк в файле string.xml? Когда-то приходилось создавать класс с кол-вом строк >5к и мне не дало запустить проект.

Comment: "не дало запустить проект" -- хорошо было бы увидеть конкретику, какие ошибки были в логах?

Comment: @Vadik error: code too large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимальное число строковых ресурсов в одном файле `strings.xml` — 32 655. Выяснил это опытным путём. Это ограничение связано с невозможностью сгенерировать соответствующий `R.class`. Если создать слишком большой `strings.xml`, то при сборке проекта получим ошибку:

```
Class too large: com/example/R$string
```

В документации подтверждения нигде не нашел.

Comment: Гипотетически максимальное число 65536 - это лимит количества полей в java-классе и в DEX-файле. Но если мы не используем multi-dex, этот лимит расходуется на все поля всех классов проекта и зависимостей, то есть в идеале максимально-возможный `R.string` класс должен  быть сконвертирован в отдельный DEX файл.

Answer (score 4):

"Логический" предел будет **65536**, так как он равен 2 ^ 16. поэтому предел в символе составляет 2 ^ 16/2 или 2 ^ 15, что составляет **32768**.

Начиная с 32768, кажется, что он урезан, поэтому я регистрирую то, что было внутри

```
Log.i("tag", "32768 : "+test32k768.length() + " content : " + test32k768);
```

И результат:

```
I/tag: 32768 : 16 content : STRING_TOO_LARGE
```

Comment: В вопросе сказано про "лимит по количеству строк", а не про лимит длины самих строк.